# some logfiles are user and group ? and not readable by root

Tags: 14.04, permissions, root, logs

```
??????????  ? ?        ?            ?            ? syslog
-rw-r-----  1 syslog   adm        15K Sep  1  2014 syslog.1
??????????  ? ?        ?            ?            ? syslog.2.gz
-rw-r-----  1 syslog   adm       1,4K Aug 30  2014 syslog.3.gz
-rw-r-----  1 syslog   adm        69K Aug 29  2014 syslog.4.gz
-rw-r-----  1 syslog   adm       1,1K Aug 24  2014 syslog.5.gz
-rw-r-----  1 syslog   adm       1,5K Aug 23  2014 syslog.6.gz
-rw-r-----  1 syslog   adm       1,5K Aug 22  2014 syslog.7.gz
```

Someone a clue?

/etc/rsyslog.conf

```
#
# Set the default permissions for all log files.
#
$FileOwner syslog
$FileGroup adm
$FileCreateMode 0640
$DirCreateMode 0755
$Umask 0022
$PrivDropToUser syslog
$PrivDropToGroup syslog
```